# How to georeference a raster where LAT and LON decimal degree coordinates are stored in separate layers in Python?

Tags: python, georeferencing, sentinel-3

I have a non-georeferenced GeoTIFF raster file with three bands:

- Land Surface Temperature (LST)
- Latitude in decimal degrees (DD)
- Longitude, also in DD

What I would like to do is to create a new raster with a single LST band, georeferenced using the LAT and LON values in the other two bands.

If you're familiar with Sentinel-3, the source product is S3 SLSTR which is available in the form of netCDF files. This entire process of converting the source *.nc files to proper GeoTIFF can be done in ESA SNAP, however, I need it done in Python.

From their source, S3 SLSTR products keep LAT/LON/ELEV information separate from every other dataset, such as temperature measurements. This is why my non-georeferenced GeoTIFF has the aforementioned three bands.

My solution revolves around generating lots of ground control points (GCP) and using them to georeference the data band. This solution, however, doesn't produce accurate results and I start getting an error as I increase the number of GCPs.

The error I get is:

`Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect count for "GeoTiePoints"; tag ignored`

In the code below, `stack.tif` is a non-georeferenced raster with three bands: LST, LAT, LON in decimal degrees.

My solution is as follows:

```py
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np
import os

orig_fn = 'stack.tif'
output_fn = 'test.tif'
dataset = gdal.Open(orig_fn)

lst_array = np.array(dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())  # LST band
lat_array = np.array(dataset.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray())  # LAT band y
lon_array = np.array(dataset.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray())  # LON band x

xsize = np.shape(lst_array)[1]  # 1500, width, aka lon
ysize = np.shape(lst_array)[0]  # 1200, height, aka lat

ds = gdal.Open(output_fn, gdal.GA_Update)
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

gcps = []  # create empty array
for i in range(0, 30):  # If I replace 30 with xsize, I get an error
    x = i + 1
    for j in range(0, 30):  # If I replace 30 with ysize, I get an error
        y = j + 1
        gcp_lon = lon_array[x][y]
        gcp_lat = lat_array[x][y]
        new_gcp = gdal.GCP(gcp_lon, gcp_lat, 0, y, x)
        gcps.append(new_gcp)
        new_gcp = None

ds.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())  # Apply the GCPs to the open output file
ds = None  # Close the output file
```

With this technique, I can project the raster but with a significant error as we move towards the east. In the picture below, I overlay the properly converted raster (greyscale, converted via ESA SNAP) above the Python-produced raster (colourful).

[image]

I am not including the code that converts from Sentinel-3 to GeoTIFF, unless you would like to see it, of course.

EDIT: It has come to my attention that *Geolocation Arrays* may help with this. As far as I can read [here](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc4_geolocate.html#geolocation-domain-metadata), this functionality is under development.

**UPDATE**

I have somewhat optimized the aforementioned method reducing the error to some extent. This solution is sub-optimal, however here it is if you wish to experiment:

```py
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil


orig_fn = 'stack_lst.tif'
output_fn = 'output.tif'

shutil.copyfile(orig_fn, 'temp.tif')  # Create a copy to work on
dataset = gdal.Open(orig_fn)

lst_array = np.array(dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())  # LST band
lat_array = np.array(dataset.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray())  # LAT band y
lon_array = np.array(dataset.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray())  # LON band x

xsize = np.shape(lst_array)[1]  # 1500, width, aka lon
ysize = np.shape(lst_array)[0]  # 1200, height, aka lat

ds = gdal.Open('temp.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

gcps = []  # create empty array
for x in range(0, ysize, 20):  # Note that max is ysize!
    for y in range(0, xsize, 20):  # Lon
        gcp_lon = lon_array[x][y]
        gcp_lat = lat_array[x][y]
        new_gcp = gdal.GCP(gcp_lon, gcp_lat, 0, y, x)
        gcps.append(new_gcp)
        new_gcp = None

ds.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())  # Apply the GCPs to the open output file
ds = None  # Close the output file
ds = gdal.Open('temp.tif')
ds = gdal.Translate(output_fn, ds,  bandList='1')  # Get rid of the lat & lon bands
ds = None
os.remove('temp.tif')
```

As you can see, the end result seems to be more faithful:

[image]

However, this is still a "trick" that fakes ground control points to georeference the raster.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I think gdal, specifically the command line utilities gdal_translate and gdalwarp should be able to handle this